# tengo un problema con mi xampp no se encontro la extensión

Tags: mysql, xampp

me aparece este error no se como solucionarlo e buscado pero no encuentro una solución de antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda lo instale y desinstale de nuevo y me tira el mismo error .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta parte quito el ; del php ini

```
[![introducir el código aquí][2]][2]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ves al directorio donde tienes instalado xampp y entra en la carpeta php, allí veras un archivo con el nombre php.ini. Busca en ese archivo una línea que pone: extension=mysqli, y que está rodeado por otras con la palabra extension también. Si esa línea tiene un punto y coma quitaselo.

Comment: si ya se lo quite y me tira el mismo error

Comment: Ya probaste desinstalando y volviendo a instalar el Xampp? Según he escuchado, ese error ocurre para actualizar una versión de PHP o cuando mueves algo que no debías

Comment: yo tambien tengo ese problema, hice lo del php.ini y no se arreglo, tambien lo he desinstalado e instalado para ver si era un error de instalacion y tampoco, en ese caso que se puede hacer?